¿Cómo cargar una clase desde cualquier parte con el mismo autoloader?
Tengo programada una API con diferentes versiones, y algunos archivos que son comunes a las distintas versiones, porque nunca cambian, por ejemplo, un archivo que gestiona la conexión a la base de datos.
Mi estructura de directorios es la siguiente:
.
└── public_html/
    └── api/
        ├── 2022/
        │   └── 01/
        │       ├── autoloader.php
        │       ├── composer.json
        │       ├── index.php
        │       └── src/
        │           ├── App
        │           ├── Core/
        │           │   └── Router.php
        │           └── Utils
        ├── 2023/
        │   └── 01/
        │       ├── autoloader.php
        │       ├── composer.json
        │       ├── index.php
        │       └── src/
        │           ├── App
        │           ├── Core/
        │           │   └── Router.php
        │           └── Utils
        ├── 2023/
        │   └── 02/
        │       ├── autoloader.php
        │       ├── composer.json
        │       ├── index.php
        │       └── src/
        │           ├── App
        │           ├── Core/
        │           │   └── Router.php
        │           └── Utils
        └── lib/
            └── Database/
                └── Connection.php

En composer.json defino los espacios de nombre del siguiente modo:
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Core\\": "src/Core/",
            "App\\": "src/App/",
            "Model\\": "src/Model/",
            "Utils\\": "src/Utils/",
            "Database\\": "../../lib/Database/"
        }
    }
}

Esto funciona entre mis diferentes versiones de API, pudiendo conectar siempre a la base de datos desde cualquiera de las versiones con algo como esto:
new \Database\Connection();

Mi problema viene cuando intento conectar desde otra parte, fuera del directorio api. Todos los espacios de nombre y clases funcionan, excepto el de la conexión.
Por ejemplo, esto funciona:
$router = new Core\Router();
var_dump($router);

object(Core\Router)#1354 (2) { ["routes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["params":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Pero esto no funciona:
$mapper=new \App\Domain\Infrastructure\Mapper\Liturgia\PdoMissaeMapper();
var_dump($mapper);

$options=array('date'=>$mDate,'endPoint'=>'homiliae');
$data=new \App\Domain\Service\Liturgia\MissaeService(
  new \App\Domain\Infrastructure\Repository\Liturgia\MissaeRepository(
    $mapper),$options
);
var_dump($data);
return $data;

Porque la clase PdoMissaeMapper usa la conexión, y no está encontrando el archivo. En el log de errores encuentro lo siguiente:
 PHP Warning: require_once(../../lib/Database//Connection.php):           
 Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
 /MYHOME/public_html/api/2023/02/autoloader.php on line 29

Dejo aquí mi autoloader.php, poniendo un comentario donde está la línea 29:
$configuration = json_decode(
    file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . 'composer.json'),
    true
);
$namespaces = $configuration['autoload']['psr-4'];

function fqcnToPath(string $fqcn, string $prefix)
{
    $relativeClass = ltrim($fqcn, $prefix);
    return str_replace('\\', '/', $relativeClass) . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register(function (string $class) use ($namespaces)
{
    $prefix = strtok($class, '\\') . '\\';

    // We don't handle that namespace.
    // Return and hope some other autoloader handles it.
    if (!array_key_exists($prefix, $namespaces)) return;

    $baseDirectory = $namespaces[$prefix];
    $path = fqcnToPath($class, $prefix);
    if (substr($class, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
        $relativeClass = substr($class, strlen($prefix));
    }
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $relativeClass) . '.php';
    $file=sprintf("%s/%s",$baseDirectory,$path);
    require_once $file; #Línea 29
});

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer funcionar esto tanto dentro como fuera del directorio api, sea modificando el autoloader.php, sea definiendo de otro modo el composer.json?

Proba haciendo require_once __DIR__ . $file; en el autoload. Y vas a tener que revisar porque te agrega una barra, si te fijas dice Database//Connection.php

por esto : ../../

@Marcos con __DIR__ . $file; da el mismo error, produciendo la ruta ya descrita en el mensaje de error: ../../lib/Database//Connection.php. He probado también un include a mano con la ruta correcta: ../../lib/Database/Connection.php pero tampoco funciona, supongo que es porque estoy fuera del directorio api en ese contexto. La solución provisional que he encontrado ha sido crear una constante con la ruta absoluta, pero quisiera cargar la clase con autoloader y saber por qué no funciona de este modo.

El motivo por el cual no funciona se debe a que cuando el path es relativo, intenta realizar la carga desde donde fue incluido el archivo autoloader.php y no desde donde está dicho archivo.

[...] Si una ruta es definida — ya sea absoluta (comenzando con una letra de unidad o \ en Windows o / en sistemas Unix/Linux) o relativa al directorio actual (comenzando con . o ..) — [...]

Entonces, una solución puede ser la siguiente, en el archivo autoloader.php:

Definimos una variable donde guardamos el valor de __DIR__
// Ejemplo
$fileDir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$configuration = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileDir . 'composer.json'), true);
// ...


Pasamos la variable a la función que registramos para el autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function (string $class) use ($namespaces, $fileDir) {
    // ...


Utilizamos la variable para realizar la carga del archivo
 require_once $fileDir . $file;


[Opcional] Para corregir el error de la doble barra solo tenes que cambiar el sprintf
 $file = sprintf("%s%s", $baseDirectory, $path);



Ejemplo:
<?php

// autoload.php

$fileDir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$configuration = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileDir . 'composer.json'), true);
$namespaces = $configuration['autoload']['psr-4'];

function fqcnToPath(string $fqcn, string $prefix)
{
    $relativeClass = ltrim($fqcn, $prefix);
    return str_replace('\\', '/', $relativeClass) . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register(function (string $class) use ($namespaces, $fileDir) {
    $prefix = strtok($class, '\\') . '\\';

    // We don't handle that namespace.
    // Return and hope some other autoloader handles it.
    if (!array_key_exists($prefix, $namespaces)) return;

    $baseDirectory = $namespaces[$prefix];
    $path = fqcnToPath($class, $prefix);
    if (substr($class, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
        $relativeClass = substr($class, strlen($prefix));
    }
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $relativeClass) . '.php';
    $file = sprintf("%s%s", $baseDirectory, $path);
    require_once $fileDir . $file; #Línea 29
});


Ha funcionado perfectamente. ¡Muchas gracias, Marcos!
